# push service change to client

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a requirement:

I have to customize a push notification to the subscribers when a service changed.

I googled and found only IOS, android have the function with their platform,but that's not what I need. I'm using the play2.

how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

With play2, the way to go is to push data to the client browser using either Server Sent Event or Websockets. Play supports both technologies.

WebSocket will allow you to have a two-way communication whereas SSE only have one way. For more information, I invite you to follow the documentation [here for Scala](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaWebSockets) or [for Java](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaWebSockets)